# How to render a webpage in a headless browser with different versions of render engine?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, headless, headless-browser

I would like to headless "render" a webpage in different versions of browser. Lets say I want to render a page in IE 6,7,8,9,10 and then get the image of it.

I was playing around with selenium but if I understand corectly I have to install all the versions of IE and then driver just runs this browsers and report the result.

Are there any headless browser that support different versions of a web browser (render engine) ?

Comment: For IE specifically, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Selenium Grid.
You must prepare few systems with all IE wersion (or other browsers), connect them to grid, and run test for all browsers.
If you have strong machine, you can use VirtualMachines for that, otherwise you must set few real machines.

Comment: Yes, that is the path I am going to take. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can only start up a browser that is installed on your machine, and you cannot have multiple versions of IE installed. That being said, there are workarounds to this. I would look into [Browserling](https://browserling.com/) which is a cloud-based service. The only effective way to run your site and take a picture on 5 different versions of IE is to have 5 different physical or virtual machines with Windows and the appropriate version of IE installed. These cloud-based services have automated this process and handle all of the details for you.